# SQL Server 2022 : problem reading Excel file using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2019, I used this command to read data from Excel files without problem:

```
select * 
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=c:\0\test.xlsx',
                'select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

But after upgrading to SQL Server 2022 Enterprise Core, this command is not working well and hangs, even causes the SQL Server service to stop!

I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: What happens if you use the newer `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`?

Comment: Looks like a long standing issue https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-x64-driver-freezing-using-open-rowset and from the info in that thread this is not actually a supported scenario. It is not intended "To be used by a system service or server-side program where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior."

Comment: @Stu I got this error: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: @MartinSmith I did these things, but it didn't matter.

Comment: Did what things? The thread I linked indicates the only supported "thing" is not to do this and use a different approach (such as the import wizard or SSIS)

Comment: @MartinSmith I can't use the alternative scenario because it costs too much and a lot of code has to be changed

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right Martin, Sqlserver does not support this, I have to choose an alternative solution.

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide a full error in its entirety.